# Ant build in Intelliji won't run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

[image]

I'm trying to run the Ant build but I'm not succeeding I can't even press the button of run it's completly greyed out

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand side you need to click the main twice where should be some xml file where, you drug&drop it into the Ant build. That way it's possible to run everything.